# Avoid page refresh after content loaded dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a side nav which refers to different pages, and have an index page with `<div id="mainItemContainer">` which has some default content. I am loading side navs page content into `<div id="mainItemContainer">` using `jQuery.fn.load()` like this:

```
var innerUrl = $(this).attr('href');

$('#mainItemContainer').load(innerUrl);
```

It is loading the side nav page into main `<div id="mainItemContainer">`  as expected, but whenever I refresh the page its going to default page/content.

What I am expecting is when ever I refresh the page (after side nav page loaded)  it should not go to default page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What you're expecting is not how it works, when you change the page with javascript, for instance by loading new content, those changes are **not** stored anywhere, and the next time the page is loaded it's loaded the way the html was originally, all changes are lost.

Comment: you should use `event.prventDefault()` to avoid browser default behavior on link click

Comment: why down vote..? did i ask any thing wrong? if so pls explain?

Comment: Downvoting is some kind of irritating sport on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to remember the state somehow in the browser. You could choose

- to set a cookie while navigating
- use the hash to append to the url as many frameworks do
- use some localstorage option with javascript

Alternativly, turn the logic around: use different pages and include (load) the same headers and footers everywhere.